# writing tasks/operators without using them in DAG

Tags: python, airflow

We are running Airflow in production and we have existing DAG that looks like:

```py
import os
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator


with DAG(
    "partial",
    description="A simple partial DAG",
    start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1),
) as dag:
    t1 = EmptyOperator(
            task_id="task_1",
        )
    t2 = EmptyOperator(
            task_id="task_2",
        )
    t3 = EmptyOperator(
            task_id="task_3",
        )
    
    t1 >> t2 >> t3
```

Now we want to add operators/tasks `t4` and `t5` gradually.

We would like to add those two operator's declarations/definitions (for a code review and merging it to our `main` branch) without actually "connect" them to the DAG:

```py
import os
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator


with DAG(
    "partial",
    description="A simple partial DAG",
    start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1),
) as dag:
    t1 = EmptyOperator(
            task_id="task_1",
        )
    t2 = EmptyOperator(
            task_id="task_2",
        )
    t3 = EmptyOperator(
            task_id="task_3",
        )
    
    t4 = EmptyOperator(
            task_id="task_4",
        )
    t5 = EmptyOperator(
            task_id="task_5",
        )

    t1 >> t2 >> t3
```

The outcome of the snippet above is:

[image]

Which is not what we want (because those two new operators will run without any dependencies), Is there a way add those new operators and keep them out of the DAG?

Comment: its not clear what you want to achieve. either add the dependencies as well or have a separated test/stage environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 options that I found:

1. define the tasks outside the DAG

   ```
   from datetime import datetime


   from airflow import DAG
   from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator

   t4 = EmptyOperator(task_id="task_4",)
   t5 = EmptyOperator(task_id="task_5",)   

   with DAG("test_dag", description="A simple partial DAG",start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1),) as dag:   

       t1 = EmptyOperator(task_id="task_1",)
       t2 = EmptyOperator(task_id="task_2",)
       t3 = EmptyOperator(task_id="task_3",)

       t1 >> t2 >> t3
   ```
2. define @task instead of EmptyOperator

   ```
   from datetime import datetime


   from airflow import DAG
   from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator

   with DAG("test_dag", description="A simple partial DAG",start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1),) as dag:   

       t1 = EmptyOperator(task_id="task_1",)
       t2 = EmptyOperator(task_id="task_2",)
       t3 = EmptyOperator(task_id="task_3",)

       @task()
       def task_4():
            ...

       @task()
       def task_5():
           ...

       t1 >> t2 >> t3
   ```

[image]

Comment: That's interesting. I tried the first option but there's a catch here. I moved ALL my operators outside of the DAG's context manager and I got the following exception: `airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Tried to create relationships between tasks that don't have DAGs yet. Set the DAG for at least one task and try again: [<Task(EmptyOperator): task_1>, <Task(EmptyOperator): task_2>]`.  Assign the `dag` to the first task solved the issue: `task_1.dag = dag`